# Why docker container can't see volume on different container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have 2 containers that I fire up using docker-compose up.
The first I just pull from the docker hub nginx:stable
The second one I build on top of the php from the hub

***dockerfile***

```
FROM composer:1.9.3
RUN mkdir /fatfree
RUN ["composer","require","bcosca/fatfree-core","--working-dir","/fatfree"]

FROM php:7.4-fpm
COPY --from=0 /fatfree /fatfree
```

I also tried `VOLUME /fatfree` in the above file to no avail.

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:stable
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/www
      - fatfree:/fatfree
    links:
      - php
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./www:/www
      - "fatfree:/fatfree"
volumes:
  fatfree:
```

If I interpreted correctly the docker documentation, my `www/index.php` should be able to see whatever is in /fatfree, but it doesn't. The folder itself shows up, but it appears empty.

If I run the dockerfile interactively `docker container run -i -t test bash` , the `/fatfree` folder exists and it has all the files I expect it to have.

There are plenty of stackoverflow questions asking how to achieve this, and they all seem to suggest that what I'm doing is actually ok, but it doesn't work, and I have no clue why.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is incorrect.

You want:

```
volumes:
- /fatfree:/www
```

The first entry `/fatfree` refers to the path on your host machine.

The second entry `/www` refers to the path in the container.

In my example, your host's `/fatfree` directory (and content) will be mapped to the container's `/www` directory.

Change as desired.

Comment: there is no /fatfree on the host machine. I want to access the /fatfree folder from the php container from the webserver container.

Comment: I'm unclear as to your intent but, if you wish to map the docker volume `fatfree` into a `/www` directory on the containers, then the mapping would need to be `fatree:/www`

Comment: that's not what I want. I want to map the fatfree folder created in the dockerfile to the /fatfree folder of the webserver container. For the point of this question, we can ignore the www lines in docker-compose.yml

Comment: After many hours of testing various things, `docker system prune -a` followed by `docker-compose up` fixed the issue. I still have no clue how to prevent this in the future, short of running these 2 commands